# Tomcat not work on CentOs - ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Tags: java, tomcat, centos

Where do I make a mistake? Which log file I should looking for the problem?

*(If I use tomcat 9.0.14 I have an error message in catalina.out:
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appr opriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
But this I can fix it with change in the 14.point config file(/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
) this one:

```
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
```

for this: `-XX:-AssumeMP`
Because I use virtual server on Digital Ocean and I have one processor.)*

BUT it's not needed if I use Tomcat 8.5.37

**So I use now this step by step...**

0.

```
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 ~]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

1.

```
wget http://xenia.sote.hu/ftp/mirrors/www.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.37/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.37.tar.gz
```

2.

```
tar xzf apache-tomcat-8.5.37.tar.gz
```

3.

```
mv apache-tomcat-8.5.37/ /opt/tomcat
```

4.

```
groupadd tomcat
```

5.

```
useradd -g tomcat -M -d /opt/tomcat -s /bin/nologin tomcat
```

6.

```
chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/
```

7.

```
chmod -R g+r /opt/tomcat/conf
```

8.

```
chmod -R g+x /opt/tomcat/conf
```

9.

```
chown -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/webapps/
```

10.

```
chown -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/work/
```

11.

```
chown -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/temp/
```

12.

```
chown -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/logs/
```

13.

```
vi /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
```

14.

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

15.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

16.

```
systemctl start tomcat
```

17.

```
systemctl status tomcat
```

18. Error:

    tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: dis                                                                                      abled)
    Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-02-08 07:3                                                                                      7:49 UTC; 1s ago
    Process: 3198 ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 3185 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES                                                                                      S)
    Main PID: 3196 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    Feb 08 07:37:49 centos-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service ente...
    Feb 08 07:37:49 centos-s-1vcpu-1gb-ams3-01 systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 1,5 year "they" (Linux forum) told me there was a bug on CentOS and I should change operation system version.